# I am trying to create a c program to get the factors of a number with array , what is going wrong?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int arrFactors[50] , i , number ; 

    printf("please enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&number); // take the value from the user

    for (i = 0 ; i <= number ; i++) // loop for storing the factors 
    {
        if(number%(i+1)==0) // condition to check if number have factors from 1 to number
            arrFactors[i]=(i+1); // if the condition true then save the value to the arr
    }

    printf("the Factors of %d = " ,number);

    for(i=0 ; arrFactors[i]=='\0' ; i++) // printing the arr 
    {
        printf("%d\t",arrFactors[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get factors of a number using array what is the wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `i` as the index to store the factors, because you're not filling in the array elements that aren't factors. Use a different variable to hold the array index. Since you didn't initialize the array, you get indeterminate values when you print the values of these elements. And if you were to initialize it to `0`, the loop would stop when it gets to the first non-factor, since you're looping until you get to `0`.

Use a different variable for the array index and the factors that you're testing. Then you don't need to keep adding 1 to the factor, and you can use the final value of the index as the limit of the printing loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arrFactors[50] , i , number, j = 0 ; 

    printf("please enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&number); // take the value from the user

    for (i = 1 ; i <= number ; i++) // loop for storing the factors 
    {
        if(number % i == 0) // condition to check if number have factors from 1 to number
            arrFactors[j++]=i; // if the condition true then save the value to the arr
    }

    printf("the Factors of %d = " ,number);

    for(i=0 ; i < j ; i++) // printing the arr 
    {
        printf("%d\t",arrFactors[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good answer for the OP.  Additionally, you also get two factors for every one you find (unless the number is square and you find the square), but you dont look like you care about speed.  Numerically you wont need to search above sqrt(n) for the factors of n, which saves time in other real world applications.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to find just the prime factors, just all the divisors. And it includes the number itself, although that could be added as a special case.

Comment: Great Mr. @Barmar you got it, is using the var. i as a counter and also as an index is a big error ? 
and what about this condition in the second loop  is it totally wrong ? 
but you did a good job with my issue and i understand your solution ,

Comment: @Bwebb yes I don't care about speed I am a beginner and i a, trying to solve this problem in other ways to get more well known with programming, I started to C about 1 month ago.

Comment: Yes, that was a big error, because you were skipping array elements and there was no way to tell which ones were skipped.

Comment: I appreciate your contributions Mr. @Barmar